# Ignore common records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `user_bookmarks` table which contains `bookmark_id` and `category_id`.
One `bookmark` can exists in multiple `categories`.

But I want that `bookmark_id` which is exists only in selected `category_id`, and if it exists in multiple category just ignore that.

here is what I tried

```
SELECT user_bookmarks.bookmark_id 
from user_bookmarks 
WHERE user_bookmarks.user_id=162 AND user_bookmarks.category_id=2308 
group by user_bookmarks.bookmark_id 
having count(*) = 1
```

but I am getting all the `bookmark_id` except selected `category_id`

I'll appreciate your HELP.

*Thank You*

Comment: So you want all the bookmarks that don't belong to any of the other categories? <- this is a clue

Comment: exactly, it's my requirement